# problem with cross-referencing in section titles / header

Tags: cross-referencing, header-footer

I am using the following as a section title in the main body:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %Patches the "chapter" page numbering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{0pt} %justification of the headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 

\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, includefoot,  
top=0.75in,
bottom=0.5in,
outer=1in,
inner=1in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{hidelinks} %Keep document hyperlinks but remove boarders 

\chapter{Chapter title text }\label{chap:sd}
some text
\clearpage
\section{Section title text \ref{chap:sd}}
\end{document}
```

But in the heading, it just says "??".

How do I fix this?

EDIT: added more code

Comment: that refers to a (presumably missing) `\label{name1}` elsewhere in the docuemnt, did you mean to use `\label{name1}` here so that you could refer to this section?

Comment: @slew123 It would be easier to understand what you want if you provided a minimal example that shows what you want to happen instead of a single line of code and "it doesn't work".  "TEXT HERE ??" is exactly what I would expect from your code, so it's not clear how you want it fixed.  (David Carlisle has offered one interpretation, another is that you want the "??" to become some other section's number.)

Comment: Please show your MWE -- we can't know whether the `??` is shown in the section or not.

Comment: Ok, I will do this, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I added the extra code, (with packages related to headers and referencing remaining) it seems to be a problem with hyperref package, not sure why.

Comment: Are you compiling twice?  LaTeX will show `??` on the first compilation.

Comment: I am sure I have, but I've double checked and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the missing reference is just the fact, that `\rightmark` or `\leftmark` use the `\MakeUppercase` macro being defined either in `article` etc. or in `latex.ltx`, i.e.

LaTeX transforms `Section Title text \ref{chap:sd}` to `SECTION TITLE TEXT \ref{CHAP:SD}`and then tries to expand `\ref{CHAP:SD}`, which is of course a reference to an non-existing label.

The basic problem is, that macros can be `\protected` from being fragile, but arguments cannot be protected, at least not in a simple manner, i.e. the `chap:sd` is transformed to upper case letters.

There are basically three solutions:

1. Change all label names that are intended to be used in a section title to upper case right from the start
2. Don't use `\ref{}` etc. in section etc. titles
3. Hide the label name in a robust macro, i.e. something that cannot be expanded by `\MakeUpperCase`, like in a safe.

The solution belows the second method. Please note, that it is not possible to use the same macroname for the robust command again, since this macro name is written to the `.toc` file unexpanded -- it will use the last known definition and not the state at the time of redefinition -- that's the cause of having `\robustref` and `\otherrobustref` -- but having more different references to be appearing in section titles this approach proves to be very tedious and is not really maintenance - friendly.

Method 1 is the better one, I think.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %Patches the "chapter" page numbering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \bfseries \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{0pt} %justification of the headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 


\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, includefoot,  
top=0.75in,
bottom=0.5in,
outer=1in,
inner=1in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 


\DeclareRobustCommand{\robustref}{%
  \ref{chap:sd}%
}


\begin{document}
\hypersetup{hidelinks} %Keep document hyperlinks but remove boarders 

\chapter{Chapter title text }\label{chap:sd}
some text
\clearpage
\section{My section title \robustref}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\otherrobustref}{%
  \ref{otherchap:sd}%
}


\chapter{Another Chapter title text }\label{otherchap:sd}
some text
\clearpage
\section{My other section title \otherrobustref}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems quite a lot of effort to change reference labels to upper case and also to declare something for each and every label. I don't understand why the behaviour of latex is to change the case of a label. This seems odd to me, particularly when many commands are case sensitive.

Comment: @slew123: As I wrote in the answer: LaTeX does not change the case of labels on purpose, it's a cause of using `\ref`  in a sectioning title, which is not a good idea, as I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has been able to fix the issue, I decided to rename the section title without using a reference.